# SQL Server 2008 Agent service wont start

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-service

We previously had SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to try some things out (I know it is by design that the agent service is disabled in this version)

After proving the concept, we upgraded to the standard edition. I did feature add with management tools (complete) and then did a repair. The SQL Agent still wont start. All SQL services are being run as "Local Service" (I can set up limited accounts after things work more smoothly)

I found an MS site that had listed my particular issue, but the steps no the "fix it for me" would not work.

When I attempt to start the service I get this message in the Event Viewer:

```
Event ID 7034: The SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS) service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SQLEXPRESS` ? You said you upgraded to `SQL Standard`...you may have broke some things while upgrading...? `I can set up limited accounts after things work more smoothly` Not sure to get it. Do you have the possibility to install `SQL Standard` on a clean new W2K8 R2 server (I ask because virtual env. are common in those day) ?

Comment: It might be relevant to know how you upgraded to `Standard` edition. I'm assuming you used the `setup /action=editionupgrade` command?

Comment: KrisFR: The DB is used by SharePoint 2007 on a physical machine. I am fairly confident that a clean install would fix the issue as I think this same issue was happening on another server that was setup by a coworker and experienced the same problems...fixed by a clean SQL install. I am a bit hesitant to do a SQL clean install on this machine until I have tested the most recent backup out.

Reaces: I believe the upgrade was done via the GUI for the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to backup all of the sharepoint databases before completely removing and reinstalling SQL server 2008 r2 standard. I had to make sure to completely remove ALL of the SQL Server directories from Program Files & Program Files (x86). I didn't do this the first time and my SQL Agent service still wouldn't start/gave the same error.

Looking more closely at it, I am wondering if there was some .CER file conflict as I saw some files labeled with SQL Agent in the name in those directories after the second removal.

For added measure, this link seems to walk you through the general steps needed to migrate SP to a new SQL server:
http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=255